# Python script to unzip and print one line of a file

Tags: python, gzip, unzip

I am trying a simple example of retrieving data from a file and printing only one line of the output. I get semicolon error around encoded and 'r'.

```
import gzip
data = gzip.open('pagecounts-20130601-000000.gz', 'r')
encoded=data.read()
print encoded[2]
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filter_articles.scpt", line 4, in <module> encoded=data.read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 249, in read self._read(readsize)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 308, in _read self._add_read_data( uncompress )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 326, in _add_read_data self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data MemoryError
```

I guess this is because the file is huge and was not able to read the content? What could be better way to print few lines of the file?

Comment: Your error is related to a perl script and you used the python tag?

Comment: Are you sure(finally) this is the error you're getting? Because python would raise `SyntaxError` here not `MemoryError`.

Comment: Ashwini I am sorry I have to edit this as I am coding and sorting out as many error as I could and then I paste what I have already overcome. Never mind I get memory Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that:

1. You meant to have quotes around the file name in your script.
2. You actually want the third line (as your post suggests) and not the third character (as your script suggests)

In this case the following should work:

```
import gzip
data = gzip.open('pagecounts-20130601-000000.gz', 'r')
data.readline()
data.readline()
print data.readline()
```